# Question about bounding PSD matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a positive definite matrix $A$ and a non-square, full rank matrix $B$ such that $B^T B$ is positive definite. Is it true that:
$$ trace \big((B^T A B )^{-1}\big) \ge \frac{1}{\lambda_{max}\{B^T B\}}trace\big(A^{-1} \big) $$

Comment: How would you define that $B^TAB\leq\alpha A$, when both $B^TAB$ and $A$ have generally different dimensions?

Comment: Thank you @AlgebraicPavel. I edited the question to reflect the actual inequality that I was looking for. I thought that this inequality can be an intermediate step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inequality is generally not true. Take, e.g.,
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix},
\quad
B=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\mathrm{trace}[(B^TAB)^{-1}]=\frac{1}{2}<
\frac{2}{3}=\frac{\mathrm{trace}(A^{-1})}{\lambda_{\max}(B^TB)}.
$$